# magento: save categories with custom attribute to custom database table

Tags: magento, categories

I added custom attribute to a Category "custom_attribute". If selected I need to save this category name and url to new table in a database that I created "store_custom_categories".
This table has columns: id, name, url

How I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Iva,You can used the magento Event function for that case.....
I am creating an extension that case....

**app/code/local/Amit/Autoupdatecat/etc/ config.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Autoupdatecat>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Autoupdatecat>
    </modules>


     <global> 
            <models>
                <autoupdatecat>
                    <class>Amit_Autoupdatecat_Model</class>
                </autoupdatecat>
            </models>
        </global>
            <global>
            <events>
                <catalog_category_save_commit_after>
        <observers>
            <autoupdatecatgories>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>autoupdatecat/observer</class>
                <method>saveCategorytabs</method>
            </autoupdatecatgories>
        </observers>
    </catalog_category_save_commit_after> 
            </events>
        </global>       

    </config>
```

app/code/local/Amit/Autoupdatecat/Model/ Observer.php

```
<?php 

class Amit_Autoupdatecat_Model_Observer
{
public function saveCategorytabs($observer)
            {

                /*get category value */
            $data=  $observer->getEvent()->getData();
                    $name=$data['name'];
        /*more fields  and write code  in below for custom table*/


            }

}
```

Comment: please write more details

Comment: Thanks for this Amit.
My Observer.php has this method:

public function saveCategory($observer)
 {
  $event      = $observer->getEvent();
     $category   = $event->getCategory();

     if ($category->getCustomAttribute() === 1) {
         Mage::log('yes');
     } else {
         Mage::log('no');
     }
}

instead of getData() I needed getEvent() to fetch getCategory()